# Plotting multiple densities on the same graph in R

Tags: r

The R code below produces three CDFs using three different approaches. How can I plot these CDFs on one graph in R?

```
#Method 1
z <- rnorm(n=100000, m=0, sd=1) 
z1 <- rnorm(n=100000, m=0, sd=1) 
z2 <- rnorm(n=100000, m=0, sd=1) 
z_app <- (z1/sqrt(3)) + z*(1+(z2/sqrt(2*3)))

#CDF
F_z_app <- ecdf(z_app)
plot(F_z_app, xlim=c(0,5),ylim=c(0.5,1))


#Method 2
v3 <- rt(100000, 1)/sqrt(3-2) 
w3 <- rchisq(100000,2) 
z3 <- rnorm(n=100000, m=0, sd=1) 
z_eff_3 <- v3 + z3 * sqrt((3*(1+v3*v3))/w3) 

#CDF
F_z_eff_3 <- ecdf(z_eff_3)
plot(F_z_eff_3, xlim=c(0,5),ylim=c(0.5,1))



# Method 3
z <- rnorm(n=100000, m=0, sd=1)

#CDF
F_z <- ecdf(z)
plot(F_z, xlim=c(0,5),ylim=c(0.5,1))
```

Comment: see the `lines` function

Comment: see also `matplot`, which works out the range of all the lines for you so you can be sure nothing goes out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Peter Flom suggests, try something like

```
plot(F_z_app, xlim=c(0,5), ylim=c(0.5,1), col="green")
lines(F_z_eff_3, col="red")
lines(F_z, col ="blue")
```

to get

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to add the keys to the graph? (i.e,  green: method1, red = method2, blue = method3). Thanks, Henry!

Comment: Certainly it's possible see `legend`